# Build shell variable dynamically

Tags: linux, shell

I need to create dynamically a variable name as follows (simplified example):

```
#!/bin/sh

IDX=1
SERIES1="a b c d e f g"
SERIES2="h i j k l m n"

# How to get this value contains $SERIES1 or $SERIES2
# depending on the value of $IDX
CURRENT=${SERIES\${IDX}} # doesn't work, just an example
```

If `IDX=1` I'd expect to have

```
echo $CURRENT
```

to display

```
a b c d e f g
```

and if `IDX=2` to display

```
h i j k l m n
```

I will need to use it in a loop for an undetermined number of SERIES coming from another script.

**EDIT**
Currently using `sh` as shell but if needed I can use a different one (even if it means I might need to convert a few things but it's ok)

My question is: How do I assign the desired series to `CURRENT`

What have I tried? The example above (that doesn't work) and other flavors like:

```
CURRENT=$${SERIES$${IDX}}
CURRENT=${SERIES${IDX}}
```

**EDIT2**

I am on the way to something:

```
eval echo $`echo "SERIES$IDX"`
```

This displays the correct series. However I can't find a way to assign it to `CURRENT`:

```
CURRENT=eval echo $`echo "SERIES$IDX"`
```

But I guess more digging and I'll find something. Any help appreciated though

**EDIT3**

Ok I found [it](http://www.unix.com/302299568-post2.html):

```
eval "CURRENT=\$SERIES$IDX"
echo $CURRENT
```

display what I expect, so `CURRENT` has the right content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://www.unix.com/302299568-post2.html) website (and probably others have similar answer...):

```
#!/bin/sh

IDX=1
SERIES1="a b c d e f g"
SERIES2="h i j k l m n"

eval "CURRENT=\$SERIES$IDX"
```

Now `CURRENT` holds the content of `SERIES1`. If I change `IDX` to 2 then I get `SERIES2` content.

Comment: Thanks mate saved my day

Answer (score 1):

This isn't precisely what you want, but if you use `bash` instead of `sh` then you can use arrays:

```
IDX=1
SERIES[1]="a b c d e f g"
SERIES[2]="h i j k l m n"

CURRENT=${SERIES[$IDX]}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd take it as last option but I found a way in `sh`